# Plotly plots not showing in jupyter lab html, but will in vscode

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, jupyter-lab

Plotly plots will not show in html jupyterlab notebook.  The plots will show when using vscode jupyterlab notebook.

I should mention, that the plotly plots did work int he html version of the jupyterlab a few months ago.

I wanted to try out vscode jupyterlab and like the html IDE better.
I am running Anaconda verison of vscode and jupyterlab

Any suggestions?

below is my import list.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Comment: Have you installed jupyterlab-plotly as documented on [plotly website](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#jupyterlab-support)? If yes, which version? What is your JupyterLab version? Did you also install other packages listed in plotly documentation? (@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager, plotlywidget, ipywidgets)?

Answer (score 0):

try below code it will render HTML

```
import plotly as plt
import plotly.express as px
data = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
#fig.show()
plt.offline.plot(data, filename = 'Test-1.html', auto_open = False)

# Show HTML
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(filename='Test-1.html')
```